# web scraping remove link without id/ class attached for php

Tags: php

Hi I using web scraping a web site, but it content too much information that I don't need.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
require('phpQuery.php');
$url = 'http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=A';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$pq = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
echo $pq['#CompanylistResults'];
?>
```

And the result is:

```
<table id="CompanylistResults">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.1800flowers.com">1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc.</a>
</td>
<td>
<td style="">$100.55M</td>
<td style="display:none"></td>
<td>United States</td>
<td>1999</td>
<td style="width:105px">Other Specialty Stores</td>
```

What I need is "1-800 FLOWERS.COM, Inc." and "$100.55M" in text from, how to do it?

Comment: this sort of financial information is available from several dozen api's there's no need to scrape. on the very page you show there is a link: "Download this list" which provides a csv file

Comment: dozen api's??? actually I would like to use those two text to create a link and display in a website

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
//the url you need to scrape
$uri = ('http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=A');
//extracts HTML from the url
$get = file_get_contents($uri);

//Finding what you want removed
$pos1 = strpos($get, "<a target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://www.1800flowers.com\">");
$pos2 = strpos($get, "</a>", $pos1);

$pos3 = strpos($get, "<td style=\"\">");
$pos4 = strpos($get, "</td>", $pos3);

//Removing the parts that are not needed
$text = substr($get,$pos1,$pos2-$pos1);
$test3 = substr($get,$pos3,$pos4-$pos3);

//Removing tags from is left after the above code, you should now have only the values that you are looking for
$text1 = strip_tags($text);
$text2 = strip tags($text3);
```

Comment: You need to better explain what your code snippet is doing so that we all understand without confusion how this is answering the question posed.

Comment: Right... in $uri put the url you need to scrape, $get

Comment: Right... in $uri put the url you need to scrape, $get (file_get_contents) extract html from the url, whit $pos1 and $pos2 u fix from where to where thake data (same $pos3 and $pos4), with $text get the code between $pos1 and $pos2 (same with $text3 between $pos3 and $pos4). With strip_tags() u get the value.

Comment: I added some comments to your code. If I am miss understanding feel free to correct the edits.